# La funcion de mi boton que despliega un formulario no es detectada

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

Tengo problemas al intentar llamar una función de `JavaScript` para que me despliegue dos `input` dinámicos en `html`.

Cuando presiono mi botón con `onclick="add_fields"` la consola me dice que no encuentra la función y no despliega nada. Debería desplegar un `input` para ingresar un número y un `dropdown` que contiene opciones que extraigo desde mi base de datos.

La función es correcta ya que si creo los campos de manera estática si funciona, el problema es al hacerlo dinámico.

```
<div id="criterios_fields"></div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input onclick="add_fields()" class="btn btn-success"  type="button" id="more_fields"  value="Añadir material">
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

var cename = 0;

function add_fields() {
    cename++; 
    var objTo = document.getElementById('criterios_fields')
    var divtest = document.createElement("div")
    divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label">' + cename +':&nbsp;</label><label class="control-label" for="cantidad">Cantidad:</label><span> <input class="form-control" type="number" style="width:60px;" name="cantidades[]" <id="cantidad" value="" min="1"/></span><br><label class="control-label" for="maaterial">&nbsp;Material:</label><span><select style="width: 100%" rel="select2" name="materiales[]" id="material_id" class="form-control select2"> <option value="">Escoge Material</option> @foreach($materiales as $material) <option value="{{$material->id}}">{{$material->descripcion}} {{$material->codigo}} {{$material->unidad}}</option> @endforeach  </select><br>';
    divtest.innerHTML+='</div><hr><br>';
    objTo.append(divtest)

}
</script>
```

[image: boton que activa la accion: este al presionarlo no reconoce la funcion de add_fields]

[image: Formulario que quiero que despliegue]

Comment: No está demás mencionar que [se desaconseja usar manejadores de eventos _inline_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these). Revisá además [var, let, const... o nada en Javascript](/q/106042). Y por si no lo conocías, investigá cómo funciona el evento [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event).